# SQL error : Cannot insert duplicate id on inserting new data with existing one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a textbox on my modify page which holds the existing data from the database. This data are separate rows in the SQL Server table, but displayed as a single row separated by commas in the textbox.

For eg : table

```
keyid   name 
--------------
  101     ss
  105     hh
  109     tt
```

In my webform it's displayed in a textbox like  `ss,hh,tt`. There's a bridge table (`Keysproducts`) which holds the `keyid` and  `productid` (product that's related to the `keyid`)

My issue here is:

On adding more entries along with existing ones in my textbox I get this error message saying duplicate values not be inserted and shows my existing id's. Below is my stored procedure for it.

I am checking if the `keyname` exists if not I insert the row, otherwise I update it. Please guide me if my approach is wrong.

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[modify] 
      (
        @keyName nvarchar(256),
        @productdbid uniqueidentifier

      )
AS
Begin
  declare 
    @productid uniqueidentifier,
    @keyid uniqueidentifier,
    @id uniqueidentifier;

    declare @keydata table (keyid uniqueidentifier);

    set @productid =(select ProductID from Products where ProductID = @productdbid );

Begin


    if not exists(select keyname from keys where KeyName = @keyName)
    begin
       insert into Keys(KeyId, KeyName)
       output inserted.KeyId into @keydata(keyid)
       values (newid(), @keyName);

       select @keyid = keyid from @keydata;

       insert into KeysProducts(KeyId,productId)
        values (@keyid, @productid);
     end
     else
     begin
        set @id = (select keyid  from keys where KeyName = @keyName)

        update keywords 
        set KeyId = @id, KeyName = @keyName 
        where KeyName= @keyName;
    end

    if not exists(select * from Keysproducts where ProductID = @productid and KeyId= @id) 
     begin
        insert into Keysproducts(KeyId, ProductID)
        values (@id, @productid);       
     end
     else
     begin
         update Keysproducts 
         set KeyId = @id, productID = @productid;
     end
  end
end
```

end

Comment: Could please explain the purpose of this statement in your stored procedure: `set @productid =(select ProductID from Products where ProductID = @productdbid );`?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think we'd need more info about how you're using this stored procedure.  If your textbox originally has ss,hh,tt in it, and I change it to ss,hh,tt,zz for example, I'm assuming you run the procedure once for every value still?  So you'd run it for ss, then again for hh, tt and zz individually?

Where do you get the productdbid parameter value from?

What constraints do you have on the table, and which one is violated (the PK, or some unique constraint)?

What exact error do you get?

I'd also like to point out that you have no WHERE clause on your last update, so you are trying to update every record in the table.  If this Keysproduct table is the one you get the error for, this is why.

```
 begin          
    update Keysproducts   
    set KeyId = @id, productID = @productid;
 end
```